# HTML/CSS Layering of Elements Issue

Tags: css, html

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxK7Z.png

border is part of a div called wrapper, and is cut off by other div/elements. Border is not an absoulte.

How can i make the border come above all other layers/elements/divs on the page?

condensed/simplified html/css:

http://pastebin.com/AsdAiLt3

Thanks.

Comment: You're going to need to add some relevant HTML/CSS demonstrating the problem.

Comment: overflow:hidden on the container with the border or make it wide enough not to be overlayed assuming the elements are in that container

Comment: @mplungjan , that worked like a charm. thanks! put ur answer as an actual answer so i can upvote it and answer the thread

Answer (score 1):

```
.wrapper {
                max-width: 800px;
                min-width: 800px;
                border: 3px solid #000000;
                margin: 10px 0px auto;    
                padding: 10px 12px;
        }

.page {
                min-width: 100%;
                margin: 0px auto;
                position: relative;
                background-color: #f00;
                display: inline-block;
        }
```

**[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshpattu/a9xVu/2/)**

Comment: it's far too simplified to be worth demo'ing. but thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Try adding overflow:hidden to the container with the border or make it wide enough not to be overlayed assuming the elements are in that container

Comment: NOT useful to downvote without a comment. Especially not after OP says it did the job

Comment: Agreed. I don't see any reasons why this answer should be downvoted.